# How to pass child nodes to an angular component?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I want to reuse a repeated pattern of my angular 5 component.

Passing some string values to the component was easy, I wrote:

```
<my-component attribute1="bla" attribute2="foo"></my-component>
```

in combination with:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component', ...
})
export class MyComponent {
    @Input() attribute1: string;
    @Input() attribute2: string;
}
```

Now, I want to pass a template-snippet to the component. Ideally I would end up with something like this:

```
<my-component attribute1="bla" attribute2="foo">
    <h1>My Content</h1>
    <p>Some text<span *ng-if="important"> !!!</span></p>
</my-component>

<!-- and at some other place -->
<my-component attribute1="blubb" attribute2="blubber">
    <img src="../gala.png"/>
</my-component>
```

How can I receive and use those nested template / dom entries in my own component?

Comment: Shouldn't that belong to the HTML of my component?

Comment: @bugs I want "my-component" to have it's own html template, which potentially embeds the snippet that it receives from the caller.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't simply put those snippets inside the template of the component. What is it that you couldn't do in that case?

Comment: @bugs at another place I want to use "my-component" with another snippet (I updated my question)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `<ng-content></ng-content>` to get that nested template / dom entries in my your component.
Basically It's in  Transclusion  concept of angular.

For more in detail [read out here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content)